# flutterアプリで画面の縁からのスクロールと中央部からのスクロールの検知をする方法

Tags: flutter

現在flutterアプリを開発中で、画面の縁でスクロールされたときは画面遷移させ、中央では無視をするという動作をさせたいのですが、実装方法がわかりません。実装方法等ありましたら教えてください。お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbsorbPointerを使えば、その領域のポインタ（タッチ）操作を無効化出来ます。
Stack-[ListView, Row-[AbsorbPointer]]という感じでウィジェットを構築するのがいいのかな。